# Custom HID Async Read give strange GetOverlappedResults results

Tags: c#, usb, hid

I have been working with a USB device (HID custom device), I wrote some code for test the device, simple things: the detection of the device connected and a Write-then-Read cycle, the task of the write/read cycle is send a 64 bytes block with the command in the first byte and the device send me back a block of 64 bytes with the same command in the first byte, the numbers from 1 to 6 in the next six bytes and the rest is uninitialized garbage, then that block is passed to a rich textbox to be displayed.

The program detect the device and the first time that I call the write/read cycle it work without problems but only the first time, the subsecuents calls may result ok o maybe not, in the case of not the read value is garbage and in some occations something occurs and vshost.exe stops work and close my program...

This is the code of the read file:

```
public bool ReadUSB18F(ref byte[] InBuffer)
{            
    int Bsize = 65; 
    InBuffer = new byte[Bsize];       

    IntPtr UnManagedBuffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Bsize);
    IntPtr UnManagedOverlapStruct = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(Overlappedbuffer));
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(Overlappedbuffer, UnManagedOverlapStruct, false);

    if (ReadFile(USBDeviceInfo.ReadHandle, UnManagedBuffer, Bsize, IntPtr.Zero, UnManagedOverlapStruct) == false)
    {
        if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString() == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            long bytesreadcount = 0;
            bool final = GetOverlappedResult(USBDeviceInfo.ReadHandle, ref Overlappedbuffer, ref bytesreadcount, true);
            MessageBox.Show("GetOverlappedResult:"+ final.ToString()+", GetLastWin32Error: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString()+", Byte read count: " + bytesreadcount.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            string error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString();
            if (error != "0")
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    Marshal.Copy(UnManagedBuffer, InBuffer, 0, Bsize);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(UnManagedBuffer);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(UnManagedOverlapStruct);
    return true;
}
```

I use two handles one for read and other to write. Doing some debug I found that GetOverlappingResult give me a true and ERROR_IO_PENDING, but bWait is true and GetOverlappingResult must wait until the read is complete at least in theory.

In a desperate effort to found a solution I put a messagebox that show the result of GetOverlappingResult, the error from calling the function and the count of bytes read but then something happened, whenever the error ocurs and the messagebox appears (showing effectively that GetOverlappingResult give true, and a ERROR_IO_PENDING), at the moment that I click OK all the data is displayed in the rich textbox as if read was done correctly, like magic, I suppose that the messagebox wait of click event to continue give the necessary time to complete the read, but that wait is supossed to be completed by the GetOverlappingResult, is like GetOverlappingResult don't do their work OR I do something wrong.

Those are my declarations of CreateFile, ReadFile, GetOverlappingResult:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile( 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] 
    string strName, 
    uint nAccess, 
    uint nShareMode, 
    IntPtr lpSecurity, 
    uint nCreationFlags, 
    uint nAttributes, 
    IntPtr lpTemplate
);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool ReadFile
(
    SafeFileHandle hFile,       // SafeFileHandle to file
    IntPtr pBuffer,             // data buffer
    int NumberOfBytesToRead,    // number of bytes to read
    IntPtr pNumberOfBytesRead,  // number of bytes read
    IntPtr OverlappedBuffer
    //IntPtr OverlappedBuffer   // overlapped buffer
);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GetOverlappedResult(
    SafeFileHandle hFile,
    [In] ref Overlapped lpOverlapped, 
    ref long lpNumberofBytesTransferred,
    bool bWait 
);
```

Declaration of the read and write handles:

```
USBDeviceInfo.ReadHandle = CreateFile(USBDeviceInfo.DevicePath, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, IntPtr.Zero);
USBDeviceInfo.WriteHandle = CreateFile(USBDeviceInfo.DevicePath, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Help me guys please, I´ve been stuck on this for a week.

Comment: Well, in the end I went for sync Rx and it worked good, thanks to all.